# Efficiently querying documents from Couchbase using sync-gateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

The public port of sync-gateway returns meta-data of documents in the bucket.

Using the `id` field from meta data it would take a one `GET` request per document to fetch all documents by using the URL `http://host:port/bucket-gateway/{document-id}`

I wanted to know if there is any efficient way to do this

Answer (score 0):

The sync gateway also provide a "bulk get" API to retrieve any number of documents as individual bodies in a MIME multipart response. The API details are available [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html#operation---db--_bulk_get-post).

Each enclosed body contains one requested document. While the bodies appear in the same order as in the request, they can also be identified by their X-Doc-ID and X-Rev-ID headers.